# Puppeteer Cluster Inconsistent Results

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've recently converted a script over from Puppeteer to Puppeteer Cluster and during testing I've observed some odd results when testing multiple pages concurrently.

Effectively I'm loading a single page and then iterating over the product options on the page and gathering the price for any product variants.

One particular product has around 9 product variants, sometimes I will accurately capture all 9 variants, whereas on the next testing cycle it may only return 2 or 3 variants.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

const Product = require('../utils/product')

const config = require('../config/config.json')
const selectors = config.productData;

(async () => {

    const urls = [
        {link: ...},
        {link: ...},
        {link: ...}
    ]

    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 5,
        puppeteerOptions: {
          headless: false
        },
    });
    
    
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {

        //instantiate a new product object
        const product = new Product();

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });

        const skuprice = await page.$eval(selectors.price, element => element.innerText);

        console.log('Sku Price:' + skuprice)

        //deal with variants
        const options = await page.$$eval(selectors.variant, elements => elements.map(element=>element.id))

        if (options.length > 0) {

            //set up a variants array
            for (let index = 0; index < options.length; index++) {
            
                const element = options[index];

                await page.waitForSelector(`#${element}`);
                await page.$eval(`#${element}`, radio => radio.click());
                await page.waitForTimeout(500);

                const variantprice = await page.$eval(selectors.price, element => element.innerText);

                console.log('Variant Price:' + variantprice)

            }

        }

    });

    urls.forEach(url => { 
        cluster.queue(url.link);
    })
    
    // many more pages
    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();


})();
```

Comment: Please provide more details, like which sites/page you want to scrape?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic javascript page should be scraped when all of the element is visible.
You can do following tricks:
[1] wait until selector is visible, check with
`await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true, timeout: 0})` 
[2] wait for desired time, but this is more flaky and prone to resulting error. 

You can simplify and rewrite your code, like this:

```
await page.waitForSelector(`#${element}`, {visible: true, timeout: 0})
await page.click(`#${element}`)
/* await page.waitForTimeout(500) <= prone to error, use line below */
await page.waitForSelector(selectors.price, {visible: true, timeout: 0})
const variantprice = await page.$eval(selectors.price, element => element.innerText)
```

Comment: Please select this answer as the right one, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else searching for an answer, it looked like some of my CSS selectors weren't working on page refresh.

Re-reading the project documentation its worth including the following:

```
// Event handler to be called in case of problems
cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data) => {
    console.log(`Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
});
```